# Help to fully understand Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I've just started to learn about Neural Networks (more specificaly CNNs) and would like to clarify some points.
I've been using this [tutorial for Neural Networks](https://enlight.nyc/neural-network#) and [this one for CNN](https://ujjwalkarn.me/2016/08/11/intuitive-explanation-convnets/).

Now I believe that I understand how Convolution, ReLU and Pooling are mathematically done, but I can't understand some other steps through the CNN process:

**Suppose that we have 1 input image and 4 filters for the first convolution.**

After the first convolution, how do we go from 4 feature maps to a bigger number of feature maps? I've seen examples where we go from 4 maps to 6 maps, which makes no sense to me. There is also this [Link](http://scs.ryerson.ca/~aharley/vis/conv/flat.html) with a visual example, but I can't understand how to go from 6 Maps to 16 Maps at *Convolution Layer 2* (this question was also asked [HERE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85767/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks) with more details but with no answer that I could understand)

Comment: One question for post, please. Two may be ok, but four definitely are not. Please split your questions in multiple posts, thanks.

Comment: Ok, sorry about it... will split

Comment: no problem :-) this is your first post and it's natural to be on a learning curve, but if you don't split the post, it risks being closed. As you can see, it has already been flagged for closure as `too broad`: even though I wasn't the one who flagged it, I think the flag is correct.

Comment: Done, thanks and sorry... BTW, can I ask the other 3 points using the same "header" of this question?

Comment: No: they are different questions, so each of them must have a different title, which gets "straight to the point" of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Each filter in a convolutional layer is required to have the same depth as the input volume, but you are free to choose the total number of filters used in the layer. Going from 4 maps to 6 maps would be accomplished using 6 filters, each of which was of depth 4. Each filter used in a convolutional layer corresponds to another "slice" (in the depth dimension) of the output volume of that layer.

Comment: But in this case not every filter would be applied to every map, beacuse otherwise we would have 6*4 final maps, each of depth 4, isnt that right?

Answer (score 0):

You should be familiar with fully connected neural networks, where the weights between a layer of $N$ input nodes and $M$ hidden nodes are stored in a $N$ by $M$ matrix.

With convolutional neural networks, the weights are stored in a $W$ by $H$ by $C$ by $D$ tensor (4d matrix) where $W$ is the width of the convolution window, $H$ is its height, and $C$ is its depth. The first 3 dimensions ($W$, $H$, $C$) are all input dimensions. So just imagine them as a very fancy $N$. The first hidden layer, (layer of filters), also has 3 dimensions, lets call them $W_2$, $H_2$ and $D$. $W_2$ and $H_2$ are calculated based off $W$ and $H$, so you cannot choose them, but you can choose $D$ which will be the depth of the first hidden layer of filters. So think of $W_2$, $H_2$ and $D$ as a fancy $M$.

In your example, to get from 4 feature maps to 6 feature maps, $C=4$ and $D=6$.